# How to use parent style in android xml

Tags: android

How to use parent style in android xml. Code is here. its not working.

And i have added layout.xml and style.xml.

Please advise for this.

layout.xml

```
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="25dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView
            style="@style/textbold"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Catering: "/>

        <TextView
            style="@style/textwhiteitalic"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Veg, 20-50, Lunch, Wedding, 15 Oct, Breakfast ..."/>

    </LinearLayout>
```

style.xml

```
<resources>
<style name="textbold">
    <item name="android:textSize">16sp</item>
    <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">#fff</item>
</style>
<style name="textwhite">
    <item name="android:textColor">#fff</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">16sp</item>
</style>
<style name="textwhiteitalic" parent="@style/textwhite">
    <item name="android:textStyle">italic</item>
</style>
```

Comment: Refer http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/themes.html
and you can refer the android built in styles by "@android:style/parent", if you wish to add your own style as parent you can use"@style/parent"

Answer (score 6):

try this you directly add parent like `parent="@style/textwhite"`

```
<style name="textwhiteitalic" parent="@style/textwhite">
<item name="android:textStyle">italic</item>
</style>
```

For more details go to http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/themes.html

**Update:** try this way

```
 <style name="txt_style_row" parent="android:Widget.TextView">
    <item name="android:textColor">#fff</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">16sp</item>
    <item name="android:textStyle">italic</item>
    <item name="android:layout_width">wrap_content</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
    <item name="android:textStyle">italic</item>
</style>
```

and set `style` to your `TextView` like

```
style="@style/txt_style_row"
```

Comment: @RamkumarRamaraj why not working? let me see your `style.xml`

Comment: my style.xml is below 
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <style name="textbold">
        <item name="android:textSize">16sp</item>
        <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">#fff</item>
    </style>
    <style name="textwhite">
        <item name="android:textColor">#fff</item>
        <item name="android:textSize">16sp</item>
    </style>
    <style name="textwhiteitalic" parent="@style/textwhite">
        <item name="android:textStyle">italic</item>
    </style>
</resources>

Comment: @RamkumarRamaraj also post your code how to used it? edit your question and add all the details there.

Comment: i am not clear with your code. can you do the changes in my code.

Comment: @RamkumarRamaraj you just copy/paste this `txt_style_row` in your `style.xml` file and apply this style to your `TextView`

Answer (score 2):

For this what you need to do is ::

```
<style name="textwhite">
    <item name="android:textColor">#fff</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">16sp</item>
</style>
<style name="textwhite.textwhiteitalic" >
    <item name="android:textStyle">italic</item>
</style>
```

--

```
<TextView
            style="@style/textwhite.textwhiteitalic"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Veg, 20-50, Lunch, Wedding, 15 Oct, Breakfast ..."/>
```